# Mouseout on div with changing height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating some custom selectboxes with jQuery so I can style them exactly the way I want them.

First I did it with CSS but I wanted the options to open upon clicking and not on hovering. The select is an `ul` with different `li`'s, the first one being the single `li` visible before the selectbox is opened.

The problem is that I have to bind a `mouseout` on the menu, but it doesn't recognise the removal of `overflow:hidden;` or changes in the height, making it so that the selectbox closes on mouseout of the first li (the originally visible 'hitbox').

I have recreated a simple example in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/u6mC2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/7uw8b/2/

Does this fiddle do what you want? I"m using the jQuery `mouseleave` event which applies some intelligence to the document hierarchy when calculating mouse exit.

Comment: That fiddle actually still says `mouseout`, but changing to `mouseleave` does fix the issue! - And I don't need to take the detour in setting the height anymore :)

Comment: Whoops, updated the fiddle link for future reference. Glad it works.